# MBProgressHUD's Frame is Faulty

Tags: iphone, xcode, size, frame, mbprogresshud

I am following the exact code provided with the sample project. Here's what I get usually:

But not always. Sometimes it runs as it should. The iPhone I am developing is running iOS 5.0.1
[image: Screenshot]

Thanks!

```
 HUD = [[MBProgressHUD alloc]initWithView:self.view.window];
        [self.view.window addSubview:HUD];
        HUD.delegate = self;
        [HUD showWhileExecuting:@selector(loadFriends) onTarget:self withObject:nil animated:YES];
```

Comment: The code for initializing and displaying the `MBProgressHUD` would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be an incompatibility issue between MBProgressHud and iOS 5. I couldn't get it to work, not in each run at least. So I ended up not using it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to initialize and add it without the 2 instances of .window, like this:

```
HUD = [[MBProgressHUD alloc]initWithView:self.view];
HUD.mode = MBProgressHUDModeDeterminate;
HUD.delegate = self;
[self.view addSubview:HUD];
[HUD showWhileExecuting:@selector(loadFriends) onTarget:self withObject:nil animated:YES];
```

Comment: Try to set the mode of the HUD as well and see if that has any effect. I have edited the code above to illustrate.

Comment: I'm guessing this may be an incompatibility between `MBProgressHud` and iOS 5.

Comment: No, it's not about mode neither. I have another project which also runs MBProgressHud on iOS 5. It has the same problem, however, it is like once in 100 runs.

Comment: Are you using the HUD creation and display code from the view controller that is displaying above?  Or in other words, if you set a breakpoint and examine self.view at the first line of your code, does it look ok?